# How do you set a cookie to be accessible across the entire domain in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I suppose there should be a way to set a cookie to be accessible from the entire domain nevermind from which directory you are setting the cookie.

Say in mypage.com/blue/index.php y set the cookie "colour=blue;" this way:

```
document.cookie = "colour" + "=" + "blue" 
    + "; expires=" + expireDate.toGMTString() 
    + "; path=/";
```

Using this code, the cookie retrieval function in mypage.com/home.php can't access the content of the cookie.

If it was just from first level directories that the cookie needs to be set, we would be ok by doing `path=../` instead of `path=/`

But how do you go about writing generic code that sets a cookie that is accessible from any page in that domain not minding how deep in the file structure is the page the cookie is being set from?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `path` just like you did, but set an additional ;-delimited attribute "domain". If you start the domain value with a `.` it will allow any subdomains (`.example.com` would effectively allow `*.example.com`).

Full documentation for the various cookie options [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie)

Comment: IE differs in the treatment of the DOMAIN attribute: http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/WinINET-IE-Cookie-Internals-FAQ.aspx

Comment: Just in case you need an example of how to put this into practise:

`var exdate=new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + 365);document.cookie="my_cookie_value=yes; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString() + "; path=/; domain=.example.com";`